# comparing two OWLs to determine similarity

Tags: semantics, owl, rdfs

I have two OWL files each file describes what a receipt is, OWL-A has class named RecBody with property hasItem. OWL-B has the same class but has a property called hasField. both are identical

My question is how specify to the RDF engine that hasItem and hasField are the same "thing" I need a solution do this automatically since I face such problem when I try to bind data from heterogeneous sources

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the `owl:sameAs` tag to do this, according to the Owl language reference.
Using this tag will make it clear to a reasoner that these two constructs refer to the same thing.

Sources: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#equivalentProperty-def

http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#sameAs-def

For classes be sure to use `owl:equivalentClass` and not `owl:sameAs` as the latter if used on classes will make your ontology OWL-Full

 Source : http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#equivalentClass-def